# url action is not working in my rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I made a salaries controller inside the folder employee.

In my routes:

```
namespace :employee do
  resources :salaries
end
```

Now in my salaries controller I added a new method `action_list`:

```
class Employee::SalariesController < ApplicationController
  def action_list
  end
end
```

From view inside index I want to call `action_list` like:

```
<%= form_for :form, :url => {:action => 'action_list'}, :method => :post,
    :html => {:id => 'form1', :onsubmit => "return checkCheckBoxes();"} do |f| %>
```

When I submit the form I get the following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/employee/salaries/action_list"
```

What could be the problem? It works fine for other controllers without using a namespace.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you added action_list onto your routes

```
namespace :employee do
  resources :salaries do
      post :action_list, :on => :collection
  end
end
```

Comment: But I dont have to include this while i do not use namespace. Do i have to include this in my all other controller using namespace. Or can i made default for this method action list to all controllers using namespace? Beacause In my other controllers also i have to include this same method..

Comment: When you use resources it will include specific actions into your routes [Rails Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

I am not sure why it would include the action without the namespace however.

Answer (score 1):

Add a route for the `action_list` action:

```
namespace :employee do 
  resources :salaries do 
    post 'action_list'
  end
end
```

Read more about adding restful routes [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).